# Microservice communication on all users page based on different ms statistics

Tags: laravel, microservices, guzzle

I have run across some issues while developing MS projects for learning purposes.

So the idea currently is that I have 2 Microservices for now:

1. User MS (UMS)
2. Statistic MS (SMS)

But on my UI I have a users page, where are all users displayed but they should be sorted by "Statistic MS" data.

Currently, I have 4000 fake users, and sending new API call for each user is insane. I have a pagination with 30 users per page, even though I'm using caching.

So it means now 30 requests are sent to get the statistics for each user this is a working solution, but very slow, and also it does not sort users based on statistics.

Because I'm getting users sorted by DESC, and just sending API call to statistics service for gathering each user statistics.

But what I need to have:

When someone opens /users page they are automatically sorted from "Statistics Service" so for example users with the best statistics would be at the top.

F.Y.I. The statistics are calculated based on user activity, that's why it's a new MS. But /users page should have a filter for this, so everyone could be able to filter through all the users with the best statistics, etc.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: What would be the best way to display all the users with the statistics from other MS? So basically i have 40 users per page, so it means there are 40 calls each page to other MS, and also it's impossible to sort the users based on the statistics in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach can violate the high availability and is inefficient. For example, if *statistics MS* is down your *user MS* will be down too. I think the best approach here can be a **self-contained** denormalized database. To be more clear, you can add a field in the user's table which determines the value of the statistic for each user.

However, this may add some complexities to your code as you have to keep both microservices (user, statistics) synched together. In this case, you can use a message broker (such as RabbitMQ, Kafka, etc) between the microservices, therefore for each statistic changes in *statistics MS*, it's going to publish an event on a specific channel which is listened to by the *user MS* to update its database.

Now you don't need to call the statistics MS for every single request and you can order the users simply by a SQL query. Also the failure of *statistics MS* will not impact the *user MS* functionality.